# Xamarin iOS - UIPageControl - Disable left/right tap to decrement/increment

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikit

I have a question that I believe is a little bit weird due to the lack of information I'm finding online.

In my program, there is a `UIPageViewController` that is overlayed by a `UIPageControl`. In my `UIPageViewController`, each View Controller has a table inside with a number of items. With `pages` being the name for my `UIPageControl`, when I use `pages.UserInteractionEnabled = false;` my tap gesture taps underneath of the `UIPageControl` and taps one of the items in the table, pushing a new view controller for that item. I don't want that to happen, but I also don't want the typical functionality of `UIPageControl`, which is to scroll left or right depending on the location of the touch. I want this `UIPageControl` on my user interface for purely the indication of how many pages and which page is the current page.

I've tried removing any existing gesture recognizers from the `pages.GestureRecognizers` collection and that didn't work. I've tried setting `pages.AllTouchEvents += (sender, e) => { return; }` which also did nothing.

A thought: I have the `UIPageControl` as a view that spans the width of the view. Could I add a `UIView` and then add the `UIPageControl` as a subview of that, and then call its `.SizeToFit()` method?

In any case, thanks for taking a look. Any help and/or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: When you do AllTouchEvents and set the event handler, all you are doing is adding a new handler, it does not replace any existing handlers.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `pageControl.DefersCurrentPageDisplay = true;` to achieve your effect.

When it is set True, the current page indicator will not be rendered until we set the pageControl's `CurrentPage` to change its selected indicator.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what I'm looking for here. While yours is a nice idea and certainly functions as it's supposed to, it doesn't achieve my desired effect. The nature of the page control, when tapped not **on the dots,** but **right beside the dots,** the CurrentPage does indeed change. I just tried it out by tapping beside the dots and then doing a `WriteLine(pagecontrol.CurrentPage)` and sure enough, it had advanced the pages, even with your `.DefersCurrentPageDisplay = true` method implemented.

Comment: @TrevorYokum Yes, the page control will change its current indicator when we tap left or right. Do you want to disable this event?

Comment: Yes, Land, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I was trying to achieve that effect without having to subclass and customize the UIPageControl. Do you know if there is a way to do this without subclassing?

Comment: @TrevorYokum It is by design that even though you tap on the dots, the page controller will not turn to the dots you just tapped. It just change its current dot one by one depending on left/right of the page controller you are tapping. So it means page controller just has left/right event, we can only disable it or enable it. The dots don't have event being fired. You can have a try: even you tap the last dot, the page controller only turns to next dot.